# My output is fine when i use "MongoDB (mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017)" but When i connect the Database with "Mongodb Atlas" it not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { deleteItem, getCartItems } from "../../services/cartService";
import { BsFillTrash2Fill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { MdOutlineRemoveShoppingCart } from "react-icons/md";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./cart.css";
import Loading from "../Loading/Loading";

const Cart = ({ user }) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  // let [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
  const shopping = useRef(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const tot = useRef(null);

  const myCart = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getCartItems().then((response) => {
        setItem(response.data[0].cartItems);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  //Delete item from cart

  const handleRemoveItem = (itemId) => {
    swal({
      title: "Remove from cart?",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    }).then(async (willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        const res = await deleteItem(itemId);
        myCart();
        swal("Product has been deleted!", {
          icon: "success",
        });
      } else {
        swal({title:"Product is safe!"});
      }
    });
  };

  // Contunue Shopping

  const handleShopping = () => {
    navigate("/product");
  };

  const totalAmount = item.reduce((sum, it) => {
    return sum + (it.product.price*it.quantity);
  }, 0);


  useEffect(() => {
    myCart();
  }, []);

  if (!item) return null;

  console.log(item);

  if (user && item.length !== 0) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="md:flex flex-row mt-24 text-2xl justify-evenly hidden">
          <div>Items</div>
          <div>Item Name</div>
          <div>Item Price</div>
          <div>Quantity</div>
          <div>Total Item Price</div>
          <div>Action</div>
        </div>
        {loading ? (<Loading />) : item.map((cartItem) => (
          <div
            className="flex flex-col w-full md:mt-0 mt-20"
            key={cartItem.product._id}
          >
            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-6 grid-cols-2 gap-4 md:gap-0 items-center text-center pt-2 pb-2 shadow-md shadow-black">
              <div className="h-56 grid place-items-center">
                <img
                  src={cartItem.product.images?.imgUrl}
                  alt="image"
                  className="md:h-46 h-36 max-w-full"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="md:text-lg font-bold text-xl md:h-auto h:56 truncation">
                {cartItem.product.name}
              </div>
              <div className="text-4xl font-bold">
                ₹ {cartItem.product.price}
              </div>
              <div className="">
                <div className="text-3xl font-bold md:pe-16">
                  {cartItem.quantity}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                className="text-4xl font-bold"
                ref={tot}
                // value={cartItem.product.price * cartItem.quantity}
              >
                {cartItem.product.price * cartItem.quantity}
              </div>
              <div className="text-4xl text-red-600 cursor-pointer ">
                <BsFillTrash2Fill
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleRemoveItem(cartItem._id);
                  }}
                />
                {/* {console.log(cartItem._id)} */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

        <div className="mt-5 grid grid-cols-6 w-full place-items-end gap-5">
          <div className="text-4xl font-bold col-span-4">Total Amount:</div>
          <div className="text-4xl font-bold w-full">{totalAmount}</div>
        </div>

        <div
          className="btn-shadow"
          ref={shopping}
          onMouseDown={(e) => {
            e.target.classList.add("btn-shadow-click");
          }}
          onMouseUp={(e) => {
            e.target.classList.remove("btn-shadow-click");
          }}
          onClick={handleShopping}
        >
          Continue Shopping
        </div>
        {/* <div onClick={totalPrice}>getToatl</div> */}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="flex flex-col md:min-h-[500px] min-h-screen justify-center items-center">
          <MdOutlineRemoveShoppingCart size={100} color="purple" />
          <h2 className="font-roboto">No Items Added to the Cart</h2>
          <Link to="/product">
            <button className="p-3 border border-solid border-purple-800 w-full text-center font-bold text-xl rounded-full duration-700 bg-purple-800 text-white cursor-pointer hover:bg-white hover:text-purple-800 no-underline">
              Start Shopping
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default Cart;
```

When I connect with MongoDb Atlas it is not responding correctly. When I add any item in cart, it is not rendered automatically - I have to refresh the page. But when I connect with MongoDB compass (mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017), it is working fine. After refreshing, I get the required output. Please help.